# Stacks implementation

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

I am having trouble understanding how the push and pop works with stacks. I understand how they work as in they push a number let's say onto the stack and the last number pushed on would be popped off. I also understand the logic behind pointers and how they work. What I do not understand is how the code is supposed to be written.

My program is supposed to let the user create a stack (determine how large it is) and then choose to push memory (numbers) on the stack or pop them off.

Here is what I got so far and I am stuck. I have researched through cplusplus.com and read pretty much everything about this stuff but still cannot figure out how the program is supposed to be laid out and how it runs.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int choice;
int * arrPtr = NULL;
int * stack;
int * top;
int val, capacity, size; 
//stack would point to the location of the first element,
// top would point to the location where the next element will be stored,
// capacity is the number of elements that can be stored in the stack,
// size would be the number of elements actually stored in the stack

int main()
{
//This is the menu
cout << "1. Create" << endl;
cout << "2. Push" << endl;
cout << "3. Pop" << endl;
cout << "4. Count" << endl;
cout << "5. Display" << endl;
cout << "6. Exit\n" << endl;
cin >> choice;

//I figured i would use choices for the menu and went ahead and wrote it out
switch(choice)
{
    case 1:
        create();
        break;
    case 2:
        push();
        break;
    case 3:
        pop();
        break;
    case 4:
        count(0);
        break;
    case 5:
        display();
        break;
    case 6:
        exit();
    default:
        cout << "Please enter correct choice (1-4)!";
        break;
    }

    return 0;   
}   //end main

void create()
{
    cout << "Enter the size of the stack you wish to create: ";
    int capacity = 0;
    cin >> capacity;

    arrPtr = new int[capacity];
} //end create function

//From here it went wrong, I cannot figure it out.           

void push(){
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter the number you wish to put on the stack: ";
        cin >> val;
        push(val)
    }//end for
}//end push
```

Please, help me understand this.

Comment: Any specific reason you are using dynamic memory allocation for stack implementation?

Comment: the user is supposed to create the stack size

Answer (score 1):

Create `std::array`.  Create iterator.  Set iterator to the end of array. (end meaning `array.end()`)

Push: decrement iterator, insert value.
Pop: return value, increment iterator.
Count: not standard on stacks, but you can get it by subtracting current iterator from end.
Peek: return value

Obviously you want to make sure you're not pushing off of the front of the array, or popping off of the back, so you should add some checks.

Stacks are really simple.  Hope this helps.

EDIT: Implementations, untested code ahead, kinda stream-of-thought'ing this

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class Stack {
public:
  Stack();
  void push(T value);
  T pop();
  T peek() const;
  std::size_t count() const;

private:
  std::array<T, N> m_baseArray;
  std::array<T>::iterator m_it;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
Stack::Stack() : m_baseArray(), m_it(m_baseArray.end()) { }

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void Stack::push(T value) {
  if (m_it == m_baseArray.begin())
    throw std::exception();
  --m_it;
  *m_it = value;
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T Stack::pop() {
  if (m_it == m_baseArray.end())
    throw std::exception();
  T res = *m_it;
  ++m_it;
  return res;
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
T Stack::peek() const {
  if (m_it == m_baseArray.end())
    throw std::exception();
  return *m_it;
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::size_t Stack::count() const {
  return m_baseArray.end() - m_it;
}
```

Comment: Count should be simply the number of elements in the array

Comment: An `std::array` doesn't seem like a good backend for a stack, because its size must be known at compile time (meaning that you can either only handle small stacks or allocate a lot of potentially wasted memory). `std::vector` seems like a better choice, but if that can't be used (because the assignment says so etc.) you'll have to go back to `int[]` arrays. (Or use a dynamic number of fixed size  `std::array`s that you keep in a linked list...)

Comment: (Still, +1 because for a stack with given maximum size, the method and explanation is quite good!)

Comment: @Subhajit, sorry it wasn't clear to me what was wanted with the count method.

Comment: @us2012, well, stacks are traditionally implemented in fixed sized containers, populated from back to front.  Maybe a deque would be a best choice.  Thanks for the +1.

Comment: Then again, that kinda negates the purpose of the assignment, no? :)

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity I'm largely unaware of traditions I'm afraid, but if that's true, even C++'s own `std::stack` [breaks with that tradition](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/). It can be backed by a `deque`, `list`, or `vector` but the reference clearly states that the top of the `stack` will be the back of the `vector`.

Comment: @us2012, I might be wrong.  The only other implementation of a stack that I'm aware of is the stacks that x86 processors use.  When you pop a value the esp is incremented, when you push it's decremented.  That's what I was basing my understanding on.  http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/The_Stack#Push_and_Pop

Comment: I have not learned about most of those things and therefore I cannot use it. I will update the program for what I got now hopefully someone can explain what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest stack using `std::vector`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class Stack{
private: 
  vector<T> theArray;
public:
  Stack(){ theArray.clear(); }
  void push(T data) { theArray.push_back(data); }
  T pop() { T retData = theArray.back(); theArray.pop_back(); return retData; }
  void display() {
    for(size_t i = theArray.size() - 1; i != (size_t)-1; i--){
      cout << theArray[i] << '\n';
    }
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Stack<int> s;
  s.push(10);
  s.push(20);
  s.push(30);
  s.display();

  int ret = s.pop();
  cout << "After popping : " << ret << '\n';
  s.display();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have compiled this code on Mac but it should work properly on Linux of on PC with bash installed.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int choice;
int capacity; /*size of stack*/ 

int stack[1000];/*THIS IS WHERE ALL THE STACK ENTRIES WILL BE STORED*/
int top=0; /* THIS WILL KEEP CHECK OF THE INDEX OF TOP MOST ELEMENT */

//stack would point to the location of the first element,
// top would point to the location where the next element will be stored,
// capacity is the number of elements that can be stored in the stack,
// size would be the number of elements actually stored in the stack

void create() //Set size of stack
{
    cout << "Enter the size of the stack you wish to create: ";
    cin >> capacity;

} //end create function


void push(int n) //Enter data into stack

{

/* Ensures that there isn't a stack overflow */

    if(top<capacity)
    {
        stack[top++]=n; 
    }


    else
    {
        cout<<"Stack FULL!!\n";
    }

    //end for
}//end push

void pop() //Remove data from stack
{
    /* Ensures that there isn't a stack underflow */
    if(top>0)
    {
        cout<<"Popped entry is:"<<stack[top-1]<<"\n";
        top--;   
    }

    else
    {
        cout<<"Stack is EMPTY!!\n";
    }


}

void count() //Count number of elements
{
    cout<<"Stack size is:"<<top<<"\n"; 
}

void display() //Print elements from lowest stack entry to highest 
{
    int i=0;
    cout<<"Your stack is:\n";
    while(i<top)
    {
        cout<<i+1<<") "<<stack[i]<<"\n";
        i++;
    }
}



int main()
{
    system("clear");  //Start with blank screen



    int exitCheck=1,entry;

    //I figured i would use choices for the menu and went ahead and wrote it out -- This is good approach!!
    cout<<"Welcome user \n";

    create(); /*Size of stack can be set only once to prevent inconsistency */

    while(exitCheck == 1)  /* This is the menu */
    {

        cout << "1. Push" << endl;
        cout << "2. Pop" << endl;
        cout << "3. Count" << endl;
        cout << "4. Display" << endl;
        cout << "5. Exit\n" << endl;
        cin >> choice; //Choice should be placed here as we need userinput during each turn 

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                cout<< "Enter your data: ";
                cin>>entry;
                push(entry);
                break;
            case 2:
                pop();
                break;
            case 3:
                count();
                break;
            case 4:
                display();
                break;
            case 5:
                {
                    exitCheck=1;
                    break;
                } /*exit in this case wont achieve a proper result in a concole based app thats why i replaced it with loop exit condition */

            default:
                cout << "Please enter correct choice (1-5)!\n";
                break;
            }

        cout<< "Enter 1 to continue else anything else to quit:\n";
        cin>> exitCheck;


    }

    cout<<"Thanks for using this code!!\n";    
return 0;   
}
  //end main
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular program all the basic operations that can be performed are implemented using arrays.

Here, the array is made private so no manipulation can be done on the array using the regular array operation instead it can only be done with the help of the public functions which are the stack operations.

The capacity of the array is taken as four initially and is doubled every time the array capacity exceeds using dynamic allocation.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class StackUsingArray
{
    int * data;
    int nextInput;
    int capacity;
    
    
    public:
    StackUsingArray()
    {
        data = new int[4];
        nextInput = 0;
        capacity = 4; //lets just assign a random capacity and later we double it everytime the capacity is used up
    }
    
    void push(int element)
    {
        if(nextInput == capacity)
        {
            cout<<"The capacity of the stack was full but is now doubled so don't worry ! "<<endl;
            int * newData = new int[2 * capacity];
            for(int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
            {
                newData[i] = data[i];
            }
            delete [] data;
            data = newData;
            capacity = capacity * 2;
        }
        data[nextInput] = element;
        nextInput++;
    }
    
    void pop()
    {
        if(nextInput == 0)
        {
            cout<<"The stack is empty !"<<endl;
            return;
        }
        nextInput--;
        cout<<"The poped element is : "<<data[nextInput]<<endl;
    }
    
    //this is the function that is used to display the elements in the stack
    void display()
    {
        if(nextInput == 0)
        {
            cout<<"The stack is empty !"<<endl;
            return;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < nextInput; i++)
        {
            cout<<data[i]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    
    //this fuction just displays the element at the top of the stack
    void top()
    {
        if(nextInput == 0)
        {
            cout<<"The stack is empty !"<<endl;
            return;
        }
        cout<<"The element on top of the stack is : "<<data[nextInput - 1]<<endl;
    }
    
    //the function returns the size of the stack that is the number of elements in the stack
    void size()
    {
        cout<<"The total number of elements in the stack is : "<<nextInput<<endl;
    }
    
    //this function helps us to know wether the stack is empty or not
    void isEmpty()
    {
        if(nextInput == 0)
        {
            cout<<"The stack is empty !"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"The stack is not empty !"<<endl;
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    int n,element;
    StackUsingArray s;
    while(true)
    {
        cout<<"**********************************************************************************************"<<endl;
        cout<<"1. Push"<<endl<<"2. Pop"<<endl<<"3. Display"<<endl<<"4. Top"<<endl<<"5. size"<<endl<<"6. Empty??"<<endl<<"7. Exit"<<endl;
        cout<<"**********************************************************************************************"<<endl;
        cout<<"Chose the opertaion you wish to perform on the stack : ";
        cin>>n;
        cout<<"**********************************************************************************************"<<endl;
        switch(n)
        {
            case 1: cout<<"Enter the data you want to insert on top of the stack : ";
                    cin>>element;
                    s.push(element);
                    break;
            case 2: s.pop();
                    break;
            case 3: s.display();
                    break;
            case 4: s.top();
                    break;
            case 5: s.size();
                    break;
            case 6: s.isEmpty();
                    break;
            case 7: exit(0);
            default: cout<<"Enter a valid choice ! "<<endl;
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```